# Track changes in SQL Server tables using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, database, logging, data-modeling

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out to integrate Python into my workload. I have a set of tables within SSMS 2014 that I want to track on a daily basis. If there are any changes to the data elements within each table, I want to track that and log that there was a change to it. I want to have that run automatically every morning without me having to run the script manually. I figured that creating some sort of a script/function in Python would be best to run all the tables that I want against it. Are there any packages, templates, etc out there that work best for this kind of situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use python for this? It's like sleeping in the truck you are using to pull a camper instead of sleeping in the camper. I'd look into the different methods to do this within SQL Server, like triggers to audit tables, row versioning, etc. Using PY, you'd get the current state... for that moment in time... not all the changes that happened.

Comment: There is a [report](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/07/sql-server-ssms-schema-change-history-report/) built into ssms for schema changes and you could use ssrs to run it daily for you if you have ssrs. This would be much easier and faster than recreating the same functionality in python.

Comment: The reason I want to use Python is noted above. I think it would be a great exercise for me to get dirty with Python. And I don't have access to SSRS Jonathan Porter, but that is a good idea!